# merge obs with delimiter in R

Tags: r

I'm using R and have following issues:
suppose I have a data set like:

```
subject color
1 red
1 blue
1 green
2 orange
2 red
2 yellow
```

I want to merge the data set which have the same subject and separate color with a semicolon, like:

```
subject color
1 red;blue;green
2 orange;red;yellow
```

the real data set is quite large, so how can I do that in R?

Comment: `aggregate(color ~ subject, df, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ";"))` OR `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, paste(color, collapse = ";"), by = subject]` OR `library(dplyr) ; df %>% group_by(subject) %>% summarise(color = paste(color, collapse = ";"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in several ways. For large data sets, you will probably

First, read in the demonstration data:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "subject color
1 red
1 blue
1 green
2 orange
2 red
2 yellow", header = TRUE)
```

And define a helper function

```
collapse_vector <- function(x, collapse = ";") paste(x, collapse = collapse)
```

Sorry if I make any mistakes; I don't have a copy of R on this computer so I'm working from memory (and [RDocumentation.org](http://www.rdocumentation.org/)).

### With base R

There isn't really a good reason to use this version unless, for some reason, you aren't able to install `dplyr` or `data.table` on your machine.

```
result <- aggregate(color ~ subject, dat, collapse_vector)
```

### With the `plyr` package

Again, there isn't a good reason to use this version here but I'm including it for completeness. This method will be slow as well, but it can be easily parallelized (read the documentation for an explanation), and it can be used in a wider variety of jobs.

```
library(plyr)

result <- ddply(dat, .(subject), function(d) collapse_vector(d$color))
```

### With the `dplyr` package

This package introduces a somewhat different style of R programming, but I'm a big fan of it. Its goal is to be used like an agnostic "front-end" for an arbitrary database system, whether that system be an R data frame or a SQL database. It's also compatible with `data.table` objects, but in that case its behavior can be unpredictable if you aren't an advanced user.

```
library(dplyr)

# the "old" way
result <- summarize(group_by(dat, subject), color = collapse_vector(color))

# using "pipes" from the magrittr package that is loaded with dplyr
result <- dat %>% group_by(subject) %>% summarize(color = collapse_vector(color))
```

Note that you can use these pipes with non-`dplyr` functions. You can access the pipes without loading all of `dplyr` by loading the package `magrittr`, which `dplyr` imports.

### With the `data.table` package.

`data.table` is a very fast re-implementation of R's basic `data.frame`, optimized for efficiency when working with large data sets. It's very powerful but its syntax can be hard to read if you're not used to it. However if you're concerned with speed and stability it's probably your best choice.

```
library(data.table)

dat <- data.table(dt)
result <- dat[, paste(color, collapse = ";"), by = subject]
```